# Merge multiple CodeIgniter result sets into one array

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach, resultset

**Data queried from the database.**

```
year 2021 = [
    {
        "month": 1,
        "total": "1,482"
    },
    {
        "month": 2,
        "total": "5,422"
    },
]
```

and

```
year 2020 = [
    {
        "month": 1,
        "total": "2,482"
    },
    {
        "month": 2,
        "total": "6,422"
    },
    {
        "month": 3,
        "total": "7,422"
    },
    .........
    {
        "month": 12,
        "total": "20,422"
    },
]
```

Here I create a method called `GetData(), I create a loop from 1-12 based on the months in a year. Next I want to combine data in an array, but how do I combine the data?

Below is my controller model which calls the same model method over and over with different parameters:

```
public function GetData(){
    $thn_now = 2021; 
    $thn_before = 2020; 
    $bulan = array();
    for ($bul = 1; $bul <= 12; $bul++) {
        $sql = $this->My_model->model_month($bul,$thn_now)->result();  // Here I make the current year parameter
        // $sql2 = $this->My_model->model_month($bul,$thn_before)->result();  //here are the parameters of the previous year
        foreach($sql as $row) {
            $bulan[] = array(
                'bulan' => $bul,
                'total_now' => $row->hasil,
                // how to display the previous year's total in an array ?
                // 'total_before' => $row->hasil,
            );
        }
    }
    $this->set_response($bulan,200);  
}
```

I want an output like this:

```
[
    {
        "month": 1,
        "total_now": "1,482"
        "total_before": "2,482"
    },
    {
        "month": 2,
        "total_now": "5,522"
        "total_before": "6,422"
    },
    {
        "month": 3,
        "total_now": null 
        "total_before": "7,422"
    },
    .........
    {
        "month": 12,
        "total_now": null,
        "total_before": "20,422"
    },
]
```

In 2021, the total is only until the month of 02, while in 2020 the total is until month 12.

If 2021 is only up to month 02 then the next array is total `null`.

Comment: Why are you posting the same question when you've already asked it and deleted it when people responded? If you need more clarification or want to add more information, please do so in the original post rather than creating a new one.

Comment: there was an error in my code yesterday, sorry

Comment: can you help me with yesterday's answer?

Comment: I'm here calling the same model only the year parameter is different

$sql = $this->My_model->model_month($bul,$yr_now)->result();

which have the same key i.e. total -> value

check my array above ?

Comment: what db are you using

Comment: postgree bro .........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This, I believe, will assist you in developing the solution. I haven't included the entire array of $year_2020, but I hope you get the idea -

```
$year_2021 = [
   [
    "month" => 1,
    "total_now" => "1,482"
   ],
   [
    "month" => 2,
    "total_now" => "5,422"
   ]
  ];

  $year_2020 = [
   [
    "month" => 1,
    "total_before" => "2,482"
   ],
   [
    "month" => 2,
    "total_before" => "6,422"
   ],
   [
    "month" => 3,
    "total_before" => "7,422"
   ]
  ];

  $output = [];

  foreach ($year_2021 as $obj) {
     $key = $obj['month'];
     $output[$key] = $obj;
  }

 foreach ($year_2020 as $obj) {
    $key = $obj['month'];
    if (isset($output[$key])) {
      $output[$key]['total_before'] = $obj['total_before'];
    } else {
      $obj['total_now'] = null;
      $output[$key] = $obj;
    }
   }

    $output = array_values($output);
    error_log(json_encode($output));
```

Output

```
[{"month":1,"total_now":"1,482","total_before":"2,482"},{"month":2,"total_now":"5,422","total_before":"6,422"},{"month":3,"total_before":"7,422","total_now":null}]
```

Comment: I'm here calling the same model only the year parameter is different

$sql = $this->My_model->model_month($bul,$yr_now)->result();

which have the same key i.e. total -> value

check my array above ?

Comment: I got that your data have a similar structure in the database, both have total as a column which later you update as total_before and total_now respectively. But I didn't understand your current question.

Answer (score 2):

1. I don't recommend that you make 24 trips to the database to collect individual totals; I'll urge you to create a new model method which delivers all of the monthly totals in a single trip.
2. I don't recommend allowing your controller to dictate the type of result set that is created from the active record in the model.  The model should be consistently returning the same data in the same structure throughout your application.
3. It seems to me that your inner loop is only collecting one row anyhow, so instead of `result()` which creates an array of objects, just call `row()` which creates `null` or an object then immediately access the `hasil` property.  Using the null coalescing operator, you can fall back to `null` when `hasil` is not a property of non-object `null`.
4. Professional programmers around the world (including ones that don't use English as their first language will recommend writing variables using English words.  This allows a more consistent language for other developers to review and maintain your code.  After all, you are using English in the rest of your php syntax, just keep it all in English.
5. For future flexibility, allow the "current year" to be passed in as a controller method argument.  This will allow you to seamlessly view historic data (should the need ever arise).  If there is no passed in argument, then default to the current year.
6. Hard coding the number of each month is acceptable because it will never change.  However, as a general rule, try to avoid using hardcoded numbers/values in your script so that it is more flexible, easier to maintain, and more intuitive to read.

Suggested code (tolerating that you are passing up to 24 active record objects back to the controller):

```
public function GetMonthlyTotalsSincePreviousYear($year = null): void
{
    $thisYear = $year ?? date('Y');
    $lastYear = $thisYear - 1;
    $result = [];
    for ($month = 1; $month <= 12; ++$month) {
        $result[] = [
            'month' => $month,
            'total_now' => $this->My_model->model_month($month, $thisYear)->row()->hasil ?? null,
            'total_before' => $this->My_model->model_month($month, $lastYear)->row()->hasil ?? null,
        ];
    }
     $this->set_response($result, 200);  
}
```

---

In my own application, I would have a model method that collects all of the data and a controller like this:

```
public function getMonthlyTotalsSincePreviousYear(int $year = null): void
{
    $this->set_response(
        $this->My_model->getMonthlyTotalsSincePreviousYear($year ?? date('Y')),
        200
    );
}
```