# Accumulate monthly totals while looping

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, sum

I have an array of data containing monthly amounts from the current year and the previous year.  The previous year always has all of its amounts, but when a current/future month in the current year is iterated it has a `null` value.  Here is an example:

```
[
    {
        "month": 1,
        "total_now": "3,000"
        "total_before": "2,000"
    },
    {
        "month": 2,
        "total_now": "1,000"
        "total_before": "3,000"
    },
    {
        "month": 3,
        "total_now": null 
        "total_before": "1,000"
    },
    ...
    {
        "month": 12,
        "total_now": null,
        "total_before": "20,422"
    },
]
```

This is [my current code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68673989/2943403)

```
public function loop_get(){
    $thn_now = date('Y'); 
    $thn_before = date('Y') -1; 
    $result = [];
    for ($month = 1; $month <= 12; $month++) {
        $result[] = [
            'month' => $month,
            'total_now' => $this->model->dbget($thn_now ,$month)->row()->total?? null
            'total_before' => $this->model->dbget($thn_before,$month )->row()->total?? null,
        ];
    }
}
```

How can I roll previous month amounts into current month to keep a running total month-to-month for each year?  Also, as soon as a month returns a `null` amount, all previous amounts should be dropped and the month should show `null` for the rest of the year.

Desired output (assuming the current month is February):

```
[
    {
        "month": 1,
        "total_now": "3,000"
        "total_before": "2,000" 
    },
    {
        "month": 2,
        "total_now": "1,000" // arr[0] + arr[1] = value 4000
        "total_before": "3,000" // arr[0] + arr[1] = value 5000
    },
    {
        "month": 3,
        "total_now": null 
        "total_before": "1,000" // arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2] = value 6000
    },
    ...
    {
        "month": 12,
        "total_now": null,
        "total_before": "20,422" // arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2] ..... = 20000
    },
]
```

Comment: Can you share the expected output you looking from above code?

Comment: I have attached the check bro

Comment: check the answer

Comment: Didn't I already answer this question?  Did you abandon that question?  Oh, I see, you accepted the other answer, but are apparently using my advice in this question.  Seems fair.

Comment: I don't understand your answer @mickmackusa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that you are dealing with integer values and your commas represent thousands placeholders.  These need to be sanitized to allow the addition to take place.

I have included the `null` checks and it assumes that once a null date is encountered in the current year, there won't be a subsequent numeric value.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/XKvfJ))

```
public function GetMonthlyTotalsSincePreviousYear($year = null): void
{
    $thisYear = $year ?? date('Y');
    $lastYear = $thisYear - 1;
    $thisYearRunningTotal = 0;
    $lastYearRunningTotal = 0;
    $result = [];
    for ($month = 1; $month <= 12; ++$month) {
        $thisYearMonthTotal = $this->My_model->model_month($month, $thisYear)->row()->hasil;
        $thisYearRunningTotal = $thisYearMonthTotal === null
            ? null
            : (int)str_replace(',', '', $thisYearMonthTotal) + $thisYearRunningTotal;
        
        $lastYearMonthTotal = $this->My_model->model_month($month, $lastYear)->row()->hasil;
        $lastYearRunningTotal = $lastYearMonthTotal === null
            ? null
            : (int)str_replace(',', '', $lastYearMonthTotal) + ($lastYearRunningTotal ?? 0);

        $result[] = [
            'month' => $month,
            'total_now' => $thisYearRunningTotal,
            'total_before' => $lastYearRunningTotal,
        ];
    }
    $this->set_response($result, 200);  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems you want it like as ----

```
$array = [
            [
                "month" => 1,
                "total_now" => "3,000",
                "total_before" => "2,000"
            ],
            [
                "month" => 2,
                "total_now" => "1,000", // arr[0] + arr[1] = value 4000
                "total_before" => "3,000" // arr[0] + arr[1] = value 5000
            ],
            [
                "month" => 3,
                "total_now" => null,
                "total_before" => "1,000" // arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2] = value 6000
            ],
            [
                "month" => 12,
                "total_now" => null,
                "total_before" => "20,422" // arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2] ..... = 20000
            ]
        ];
        $totalNow = 0;
        $totalBefore = 0;
        $array1 = [];
        foreach ($array as $arr) {
            if ($arr['total_now'] != null) {
                $arr['total_now'] = $totalNow += (float) preg_replace('/\D/ui', '', $arr['total_now']);
            }
            if ($arr['total_before'] != null) {
                $arr['total_before'] = $totalBefore += (float) preg_replace('/\D/ui', '', $arr['total_before']);
            }
            $array1[] = $arr;
        }
```

Comment: Why in the world do you have `u` and `i` pattern modifiers on a pattern that only contains `\D`?

Comment: I've tried it, but when looped, the total for months 9-12 2021 should be null, can you give an example in my code?

there I called two models with different years with row

Comment: if using foreach , which model should i loop ?

Comment: These loose comparisons will mistake zero values for nulls.